# 3 students share a room in a dormitory. they have 4 cups, 5 saucers, and 3 teaspoons,

Tags: probability, statistics

3 students share a room in a dormitory. They have $4$ cups, $5$ saucers, and $3$ teaspoons, all different. In how many ways can they set the table for tea? (each set consists of a cup, saucers, and a teaspoon)

Answer (score 1):

Cups can be put down in $4 \times 3 \times 2$ ways, the saucers in $5 \times 4 \times 3$ ways, and the teaspoons in $3 \times 2 \times 1$ ways. So we must multiply these three numbers together to get all possible combinations.